# Syntax Error when $eval a string inside a directive under ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

My directive:

```
app.directive('showTitle', () => ({
    restrict: 'A',
    link (scope, ele, attrs){
        console.log(ele.text());
        if (/\{\{.*\}\}/.test(ele.text())) {
            ele.attr('title', scope.$eval(ele.text()));
        } else {
            ele.attr('title', ele.text());
        }
    }
})
```

My template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in record.records">
    <p show-title>{{item.module}}</p>
</div>
```

I've tried removing `{{}}`, but that doesn't work either.

> angular.js:9383 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token
>   'item.module' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the
>   expression [{{item.module}}] starting at [item.module}}].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st place you don't need to explicitly evaluated the interpolated binding, angular will take care of that, it evaluate mustache `{{}}` expression directly while compiling DOM.

It might be the case that you have configured `$interpolateProvider` to something else like `[[` `]]`/ `<<` `>>`, so that's why you need this manual conversion, So you could do it explicitly you could use `$interpolate` service to evaluate value.

```
ele.attr('title', $interpolate(ele.text())(scope));
```

Comment: Great. That should be `$interpolate(ele.text())(scope)`